# How to do forms in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5

What is the proper way to work with forms in laravel? In symfony there are form "Type" classes, where you define forms, and then in view you just render fields out of "Type" object.

I didn't found anything like that in laravel. Does it mean, that you just write HTML form inside template, and then get values directly out of request object?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know much about the **Symphony** but in laravel, you can simply create form with **HTML** or you can use the **Laravel Collective Form** . You can get more information about Laravel Collective Form in this link: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html.

And you can pass the form data to controllers using POST,PUT,PATCH methods and save the data to the database. I hope this helped you.

Comment: whats the pros and cons of both ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the form contents by `$request->input('param')`.

Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#retrieving-input) for further information.